# Is a conic hull of any arbitrary set not a strictly convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls, convex-cone

A conic hull of an arbitrary set can be a strictly convex set?

Please look at the figure below, the set is a triangle which is not closed. What is its conic hull?

[image]

in the figure, the conic hull is the union of origin and an open set. So, it is strictly convex (no line on the boundary)?

Comment: There's some ambiguity in the English here.  Do you mean "A conic hull of an arbitrary set is not necessarily a strictly convex set" or "A conic hull of an arbitrary set is never a strictly convex set."  The first is true, while the second is false.  Here, "but not" could mean that the implication "A conic hull of an arbitrary set is a strictly convex set" is false or "not" could be part of the conclusion of the implication.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, Thanks. your second sentence was my point "A conic hull of an arbitrary set is never a strictly convex set."

Comment: To me the first interpretation seems more natural, and I expect that it is what the author intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

The conic hull of an open set is the union of an open set and the origin, and this is strictly convex.   But a convex cone that contains one of its boundary points other that $0$ is not strictly convex, so these are essentially the only counterexamples.  The conic hull $\text{coni}(S)$ of a set $S$ is strictly convex if and only if $\text{coni}(S)$ is $\{0\}$ or the conic hull of an open set.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is true- In $R^{2}$, if I take the set $S={x | (x_{1}^{2}+(x_{2}-1)^{1} \leq 1$, the conic hull is the open half space $x_{2} > 0$ together with the origin.  That conic hull is strictly convex.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I'll edit.